# Google map marker with angularjs for large data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, excel, google-maps

I am building an widget where user can upload an excel file and the places are get marked in the google map.

The following code works, but issue comes when i am reading an large excel file with 10k amount of data, the browser gets stuck. I am using a for loop and adding some timeout to get the data from the google api.

I pass the city name and get the latitude and longitude and mark it on the map.
Is there a better way i can implement?

Here is the code:

```
function googleMapsInit(widId, $scope, $http, $rootScope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.finish = function() {
        var objIndex = getRootObjectById(widId, $rootScope.dashboard.widgets);
        $mdDialog.hide();
        document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = "";
        //excel data
        var array = JSON.parse($rootScope.json_string);
        $scope.locationData = [];
        //dividing it to chunks
        var k,j,temparray,chunk = 8;
        for (k=0,j=array.length; k<j; k+=chunk) {
            temparray = array.slice(k,k+chunk);
            var i;
            //getting the longitude and latitude from the google geo api
            for(i=0;i < temparray.length ; i++){
               Geocode(temparray[i].PLACE_OF_ACCIDENT);   
            }       
        }       
        //sometimes data gets delayed
        setTimeout(function(){ googleMap(); }, 5000);                 

    };
    function Geocode(address) {
        var obj = {};
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        obj = {
                            lat : results[0].geometry.location.G,
                            lng : results[0].geometry.location.K
                        };
                        setTimeout(function(){ $scope.locationData.push(obj); }, 100);
                   }
                    else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {    
                        setTimeout(function() {
                        Geocode(address);
                        }, 100); 
                    }
                    else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_LIMIT) {    
                        setTimeout(function() {
                        Geocode(address);
                        }, 100); 
                    }
                    else {                     
                    }       
        });     
    }
   function googleMap() { 
        var dataStore = $scope.locationData;
        var array = JSON.parse($rootScope.json_string);
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            center: {lat: 7.85, lng: 80.65},
            zoom: 6 });
        var pinImageGreen = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png");
        var pinImageBlue = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png");
        var marker = [];
        var k;
        for(k=0; k < array.length; k++){
                   marker[k] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: $scope.locationData[k].lat, lng: $scope.locationData[k].lng},
                    map: map,
                    title: array[k].PLACE_OF_ACCIDENT,
                    icon: pinImageGreen,
                    VEHICLE_TYPE: array[k].VEHICLE_TYPE,
                    VEHICLE_USAGE: array[k].VEHICLE_USAGE,
                    VEHICLE_CLASS: array[k].VEHICLE_CLASS
                    });
                    marker[k].addListener('click', function(data) {
                        var j;
                        for(j=0;j<array.length;j++){

                            if(($scope.locationData[j].lat == data.latLng.G)  && ($scope.locationData[j].lng == data.latLng.K )){                                
                                document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = 
                                array[j].PLACE_OF_ACCIDENT + "</br>" +
                                array[j].VEHICLE_TYPE + "</br>" +
                                array[j].VEHICLE_USAGE + "</br>" +
                                array[j].VEHICLE_CLASS + "</br>" ;
                            }  
                        }    
                    });      
            }
    }

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };

}
```

Comment: Hey, in case my answer has helped you, would you mind marking it as a the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to slightly improve performance is this: Instead of adding markers to the map one at a time, just create the markers array separately and then add them all at once to the map. Here is a sample code:

```
var markersData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            var item = scope.myArray[i];
            if (item.lat != undefined && item.lon != undefined) {
                var icon = 'icon.png';
                markersData.push({
                    lat: item.lat,
                    lng: item.lon,
                    title: 'xyz'
                });
            }
        }

        map.addMarkers(markersData);
```

By the way I have used "gmaps.js" for this which simplifies coding google maps, but you don't necessarily need it. The general idea is to avoid adding markers to the map inside the loop, one by one.